# How to interpret fixed effect regression R-sq. results for panel data?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, paneldata, stata

I runned a fixed effect regression in Stata (xtreg, fe) for panel data. I obtained below R-sq. results. How should I interpret them? Which one is my main interest(within,below or overall)? How can I derive the exact Adjusted R-sq. by using these 3 values?

R-sq:
     within  = 0.8226
     between = 0.4727
     overall = 0.5311

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In general, you should care most about the within R^2.

Answer (score 2):

In panel regressions you have multiple dimensions and that is why also you have 3 different $R^2$. The within $R^2$ tells you how much variation within your panel variables is on average explained by your model. The between $R^2$, tells you how much variation between your panel variables is explained by the model, and overall $R^2$ gives you the combination of both and tells you how much variation in the whole panel data your model explains.

According to the stata manual you should get adjusted $R^2$ for fixed effects by `ereturn list` it will be the r2_a scalar. However, there are no simple adjustments for within and between $R^2$, those are most often reported unadjusted.

Answer (score 0):

The ANOVA results indicate 53.11% of dependent  variable is explained - which you should check whether it is significant (or insignificant). Moreover, you may ascertain the chi-square with the help of between and within sum of squares. This could help you to test the significance level at which the effect on dependent variable is significant.